# ie7 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone explain why this is throwing an error in IE7? It's indicating the error is happening on the line with "var newStr....."

It's not happening in any other browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[onclick*="_self"]').each(function() {
        var newOnclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
        var newStr = newOnclick.replace('_self','_parent');
        $(this).attr('onclick', newStr);
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the type of `newOnclick`? (Seems like a pretty... fragile way of modifying handlers, by the way; is it possible to change the links themselves?)

Comment: did you try just doing all that in one line? 
`$(this).attr('onclick',$(this).attr('onclick').replace('_self','_parent'));`

Comment: `var newOnclick = $(this).attr('onclick');`newOnclick = newOnclick.replace('_self','_parent');`

Comment: Even on browsers where this does work, it's really bad practice.  Using in-line JavaScript to begin with, then performing string operations on the representation and creating new functions?  There is very likely a better way to do what you want.

Comment: OK just to clear up a few points:
I'm working with a 3rd party site that I can not modify the contents only the header / footer. So no I can not just change the link to what I want. 
Also just to be clear the onclick function is a long one and I just need to replace the _self to _parent.
Unfortunately I do not have control over what's in the page. I'm integrating a 3rd party application into another site via iframe which I have no control of.

Comment: @kennypu This threw the same error as the original code (but works in other browsers)

Comment: @a_maar this doesn't seem to work at all

Answer (score 1):

(Earlier versions) of IE cannot cast a function object to it's source as you request it. Thus, the strings cannot be exchanged that easily.

You can either replace the whole old "_self" function by a new _parent function, e.g.:

```
$('a[onclick*="_self"]').attr('onclick', function() { _parent-stuff });
```

or - I read your last comment and the second solution won't work for you as it would require changing the HTML of the body.

Comment: My solution corrects the syntax of the OP's proposed function, so I am unclear on why it "won't work"...

Comment: Iam addressing the Op in my answer. Though, the Op states that the error is in the replace-line which you copied.

Comment: While I could just force replace the whole thing. I am not managing the code I'm altering and I'd like it to be a big more future proof by grabbing the current live string (in case the 3rd party changes it), just being sure to make it submit to _parent not _self as I'm essentially getting it OUT of the iframe I'm embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[onclick*="_self"]').each(function() {
    var newOnclick = $(this).attr('onclick').toString();
    var newStr = newOnclick.replace('_self','_parent');
    if($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) == 7) {
       newStr = newStr.replace('onclick="function anonymous()&#10;{&#10;','onclick="');
       newStr = newStr.replace('}"','"');
    }
    $(this).attr('onclick', newStr);
    //$(this).unbind();
    //$(this).bind('click', function () { eval(newStr); });
  });
});
```

Comment: Will this work? Surely `newStr` will include the `function(){` ... `}` wrapper, not just the executable statements. I think you have to use `new Function()`.

Comment: Actually: `$(this).attr('onclick', newStr);` simply may work. The reported problem should be solved with `toString()`, but I replacing the attribute may leave the original event handler...

Comment: `$(this).attr('onclick', newStr);` looks better. If it works, then the original handler will be replaced, unlike with jQuery's `.on()` or `.bind()` which progressively accumulate handlers.

Comment: Op says, the error is in the replace-line and not the line you elaborated on, though...

Comment: I think the `replace()` method fails because the `var newOnclick` is not a string.

Comment: newOnClick is a function object.

Comment: And `toString()` converts `newOnclick` to a string so that the `replace()`method can be used.

Comment: OK the thing that is getting closest is the original concept adding the .toString()
With this method it's working in all the other browsers.. but in IE7 the new string is wrong.. it looks something like this:
`onclick="function anonymous()&#10;{&#10;return SearchBox.doSearch('EN','_parent',.....[stuff here]......;&#10;}"`

and it should be like this:
`onclick="return SearchBox.doSearch('EN','_parent',.....[stuff here].......;"`

Comment: If you don't want to (or can't) work with the anonymous function wrapper, you could conditionally replace the beginning and end of the string so you get the desired string for IE7.

Comment: @shaun5 This is now getting over my head. I don't know what that wrapper is and why it only shows for ie7. Why is that and how can it be worked around? As it sits that onlcick function does not execute in ie7.

Comment: @Jesse, I have updated my answer with my suggestion (and gone back to your original way of redefining the click handler).